# javascript timezone conversion using momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I have a date and time in UTC and a timezone I want to convert this date and time to the given timezone equivalent e.g. if UTC date is 2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z that means 10 Jan 00:00 am and when I convert it to NewYork timezone equivalent output should be given as
2022-01-09T19:00:00.000Z that is 9 Jan 07:00 pm or 19:00 because it has -05:00 hour from UTC.
how I can achieve that can anyone help?
timezone can be any timezone.
Thanks for your help.

```
like 
let date= '2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z';
let timezone = 'America/New_York';
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? The [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/) of momentjs is always a good starting point

Comment: thank you Andreas I have tried some and followed the documentation you mentioned but I didn't get the expected result. That's why I'm posting here.

Comment: Then show your attempt and we will help you fix that. Right now your question is just a "give me the solution please" which is not what SO is about -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `moment-timezone` like this:

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

const date = '2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z';
const timezone = 'America/New_York';

const convertedDate = moment.utc(date)  // create Moment object from date in UTC
  .tz(timezone)                        // convert to provided time zone
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A')    // display in format

console.log(convertedDate)
// 2022-01-09 07:00:00 PM
```